Reconciling two equations for operator sum representation
Over here the operator sum representation formula is given as:

but over here it is given as:

can anyone explain me how are these two equivalent?

Say that $\mathcal{H}$ is the Hilbert space of your system and $\mathcal{H}_E$ is the Hilbert space of the environment. Then there are two differences:

The second equation uses shorter notation for states on $\mathcal{H}\otimes \mathcal{H}_E$. You can interpret $_E\langle a|$ as $(I_\mathcal{H} \otimes \langle e_a|_{env})$, so that $_E\langle a|$ can be viewed as a linear map of the form $\mathcal{H}\otimes \mathcal{H}_E \rightarrow \mathcal{H}$. The first equation makes the domain of this map more explicit.
In the second equation, the $\mathbf{U}$ operator is an isometry of the form $\mathcal{H} \rightarrow \mathcal{H}\otimes \mathcal{H}_E$, while in the first equation $U$ is a unitary of the form $\mathcal{H}\otimes \mathcal{H}_E \rightarrow \mathcal{H}\otimes \mathcal{H}_E$. So in the first equation, you can think of the operator $(I_\mathcal{H} \otimes |e_0\rangle_{env})$ acting on the right of $U$ as transforming the unitary into an isometry of the same form as the second equation, i.e.
$$
\mathbf{U} := U(I_\mathcal{H} \otimes |e_0\rangle_{env}).
$$
Then the equations are equivalent.

